# Google Chrome for Android remote web debugging

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Gooday,
  I am using a *Samsung Galaxy S3* Android phone to attempt to debug a mobile website that I am developing.  I am trying to take advantage of the Remote Debugging google has started to offer through Chrome for Android.

I have gone through this walkthrough successfully:
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging

When I click Inspect the popup resembles a Chrome Dev Tools window with no content.  I have tried this on multiple sites.  I have no firewalls up.  No anti-virus active, I've restarted, run the commands in the above link over again and even attempted it on a friend's *Galaxy S2*. I still get the same thing on multiple sites; the empty Dev Tools window.

Has anyone experienced this? Does anyone have a possible solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure to follow https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging including the troubleshooting tips:

- Make sure you are using modern Chrome version as your client browser. It should be equal or greater version than the Android Chrome you are debugging.
- On your device, verify you have Developer Options available, and USB debugging turned on. If it's working and connected, it'll set a notification on your device.
- If USB debugging is on, but `about:inspect` doesn't show your device check that Discover USB devices is checked. If so, unplug the device and try revoking all USB authorizations in Developer Options to retry.
- If those don't help, you can open Chrome's Dev Tools on that poorly loaded page and hit reload. Console might show errors, Network tab might show unsuccessful WebSocket connections to the device. Both might help investigating the issue you file at http://new.crbug.com

Comment: Your second bullet point did it for me. I just had to restart the phone and we were all good.

Comment: The update worked for me. A note for people with the same problem, android will not auto update your Chrome app if the permissions have changed. So while you might assume it's up to date and still failing, it's actually failing because the versions don't match up.

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to App Store on device.
2. Search for Chrome
3. Click the update button (assuming it is not up to date)

This is what it was for me.

Answer (score 1):

Very similar problem for me, seems adb doesn't actually check your spelling on the command line options, it is quite happy to accept:

```
adb forward tcp:9222 localbastract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

when it really wants:

```
adb forward tcp:9222 localabstract:chrome_devtools_remote
```

If I could figure out where to report this bug I would, but they don't appear to have an easily findable bug tracker.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use chrome beta on your phone. That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the version on your mobile devices is the same as on your desktop one.

Answer (score 0):

Update the android chrome google to updated version. Fixed for me. Nexus 4

Answer (score 0):

Chrome found my phone after "adb devices" only, which started daemon and show my device in list. Nothing more helps.

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of the solutions but non worked for me, so here is my current  workaround...

On the blank/empty Dev Tools window press '**Ctr+Shift+i**'. This opens a **2nd** Dev Tools window. 
You will see an error in the console “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addExtensions'” and on the right one of these 2 links :

A) "VM45:72"
=> bad luck. Close 2nd window and try again.

B) "**(program):72**"
=> that’s it. click on the link "(program):72" and  the 1st debug window will work again !

It may take one to 10 times before the "(program):72" appears

Answer (score 0):

try different USB port. This might be Chrome's problem, but in some cases its something in driver\computer configuration or faulty hardware. Different USB port solved the problem in my case